# Evitar vazamento de memória em função de retorno

Tags: c++, orientação-a-objetos, gerenciamento-de-memória

Tem um exercício no livro de C++ que pede para criar uma função que retorne um objeto evitando o vazamento de memoria. Eu fiz assim mas não tenho certeza se realmente funciona:

```
class Point1{
    public : int x;
    public : int y;

    Point1(int x,  int y  );
    ~Point1();
};

Point1::Point1( int x1,  int y1    ){
this->x=x1;
y=y1;
std::cout <<"oioi"<<std::endl  ;
}

Point1::~Point1(){
    std::cout <<"destruu"<<std::endl ;

}

Point1 * retorno(){

     Point1* C = new Point1(1,4);

     cout<< endl;
     return C;
}

int main() {


     Point1*C=retorno();

     cout << C ;
     cout<< endl;
     cout<< endl;
     cout<< C->x;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: sim , mas nesse caso quero criar o obj na funcao e aloca lo na heap e retorna para dstruir com o delete

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 1):

Não tente escrever Java em C++, escreva C++ e esqueça como fazia em Java. Escrevendo do jeito certo funciona e não há vazamentos. Não tem porque esse código produzir vazamento.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Point1 {
public:
    int x;
    int y;

    Point1(int x, int y);
    ~Point1();
};

Point1::Point1(int x1, int y1) {
    x = x1;
    y = y1;
    cout << "criou" << endl; //estou deixando só para fins didáticos
}

Point1::~Point1() {
    cout << "destruiu " << x << " " << y << endl; //para fins de debug
}

int main() {
    Point1 C(1, 4);
    cout << C.x << endl;
    cout << C.y << endl;
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/joIVCI). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/iatiusbo-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Memory/Destruction.cpp).

Se quiser fazer o que não deve nesse caso, pode fazer com [*smart pointers*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr), que é o jeito correto de lidar com gerenciamento de memória no *heap*.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

class Point1 {
public:
    int x;
    int y;

    Point1(int x, int y);
    ~Point1();
};

Point1::Point1(int x1, int y1) {
    x = x1;
    y = y1;
    cout << "criou" << endl; //estou deixando só para fins didáticos
}

Point1::~Point1() {
    cout << "destruiu " << x << " " << y << endl; //para fins de debug
}

unique_ptr<Point1> retorno() {
    unique_ptr<Point1> C(new Point1(1,4));
    return C;
}

int main() {
    auto C = retorno();
    cout << C->x << endl;
    cout << C->y << endl;
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/KXITp5). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/jlmlkugb-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Memory/Destruction2.cpp).

Comment: sim , mas nesse caso quero criar o obj na funcao e aloca lo na heap e retorna para dstruir com o delete –

Comment: ou seja queria destruir o objeto alocado com o operador new Point1* C = new Point1(1,4);

Comment: por isso pegue o retorno e passei por ponterio    "Point1*C" o problema é que nao sei se  o  ponterio  ''''Point1*C=retorno();"''' realmento poderia destruir o  new point da funçao

Comment: Aquela função não estava fazendo nada útil por isso matei ela. Não tem porque criar isso no *heap*. Mas se querer criar mesmo, crie e depois apague na mão com `delete`. Ou use *smart pointers* que é o jeito correto de fazer isto. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/50165/101 e http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/83894/101. Você está pensando como programador Java, isso não vai dar certo. Editei para mostrar essa opção.

Comment: ok obg por responde eu estou lendo livro de c++ basicamente estava seguido um exemplo esse olha

Comment: ok obg , estou tentando apreende c++ ,com um lvro vc teria algum pra me recomendar

Comment: Não gosto de recomendar livros porque são raros os bons, e principalmente atualizados de verdade, e o adequado para cada pessoa varia muito, tem alguns exemplos na *tag*: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/c%2b%2b/info

Comment: ou algum tutorial principalmente de ponterios eu entendi a sintaxe e o jeito de manipula mas nao acho q como vim do c++ nao consgo acimila bem o uso deles vc tem algo libro ou tutoria para iniciante apreende

Comment: Tutoriais costumam ser feitos meio de qualquer jeito, eu nunca indico, principalmente porque quem mais gosta de tutoriais são as pessoas que menos devem usá-los.

Comment: ok obg pela reposta  vou  tentar apreende mais sobre ponteiros isso ainda nao entrou direto na minha mente ,valeu pela ajuda

Comment: Se a pergunta resolveu o que queria pode aceitá-la. Mais pra frente quando tiver reputação suficiente poderá votar em tudo no siote também. Veja o [tour].