# Vazamento de memória no return

Tags: c++, orientação-a-objetos, memória

Estou lendo um livro e me deparei com esse código:

```
class SimpleCat
{
    public:
    SimpleCat (int age, int weight);
    ~SimpleCat() {}
    int GetAge() { return itsAge; }
    int GetWeight() { return itsWeight; }

    private:
    int itsAge;
    int itsWeight;
};

SimpleCat::SimpleCat(int age, int weight):
itsAge(age), itsWeight(weight) {}

SimpleCat & TheFunction();

int main()
{
    SimpleCat & rCat = TheFunction();
    int age = rCat.GetAge();
    cout << "rCat is " << age << " years old!\n";
    cout << "&rCat: " << &rCat << endl;
    // How do you get rid of that memory?
    SimpleCat * pCat = &rCat;
    delete pCat;
    // Uh oh, rCat now refers to ??
    return 0;
}

SimpleCat &TheFunction()
{
    SimpleCat * pFrisky = new SimpleCat(5,9);
    cout << "pFrisky: " << pFrisky << endl;
    return *pFrisky;
}
```

A minha dúvida é:

O livro diz que há um vazamento de memória no `retun` da chamada de `SimpleCat & rCat = TheFunction()` devido ao alocamento de memória no escopo. Queria saber com resolver isso.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A função `TheFunction` faz o seguinte:

```
SimpleCat * pFrisky = new SimpleCat(5,9);
```

Essa linha aloca dinamicamente uma instância da classe `SimpleCat`, aponta o seu endereço de memória na variável (ponteiro) `pFrisky` e retorna esse endereço de memória *como uma referência*.

Já fora na chamada de `main`, a função `TheFunction` foi chamada assim:

```
SimpleCat & rCat = TheFunction();
```

De forma que aquela instância criada dinamicamente agora está sendo referenciada em um outro endereço, definido de forma não-dinâmica na variável `rCat` (que, note, **não é um ponteiro**).

Ambas as chamadas abaixo imprimem o endereço de memória onde o objeto se encontra:

1. `cout << "pFrisky: " << pFrisky << endl` (na função `TheFunction`)
2. `cout << "&rCat: " << &rCat << endl;` (na função `main`)

Eu não executei para ter certeza, mas você provavelmente perceberá que são **endereços diferentes** (porque a segunda variável, `rCat`, não foi alocada dinamicamente.

> Edit: Eu executei [no Ideone](http://ideone.com/Z0ZX1b) pra ter
>   certeza, e *não necessariamente* os endereços impressos serão
>   diferentes. Ainda assim, os objetos são alocados *em locais distintos*
>   (leia sobre a diferença entre o [heap e o stack aqui mesmo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/73)), e por
>   isso o vazamento.

Logo, quando você tenta deletar aquela área alocada dinamicamente fazendo:

```
SimpleCat * pCat = &rCat;
delete pCat;
```

Na verdade vc tá fazendo uma bela de uma cag... digo, bobagem. :)

Como resolver? Se você aloca dinamicamente, retorne um ponteiro mesmo:

```
SimpleCat *TheFunction()
{
    SimpleCat * pFrisky = new SimpleCat(5,9);
    cout << "pFrisky: " << pFrisky << endl;
    return pFrisky;
}
```

Aí, no `main`, você faz:

```
SimpleCat * rCat = TheFunction();
. . .
delete rCat;
```

Comment: Só complementando que isso vale para um exercício simples assim. Inclusive se não der o `delete` não vai acontecer nada de errado porque o código vai encerrar logo depois. Em códigos reais e modernos sempre que usa um `delete` provavelmente está fazendo algo errado. Eu já havia falado sobre isso pra ele: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/174932/101

Comment: "Em códigos reais e modernos sempre que usa um delete provavelmente está fazendo algo errado." Fantástico! :)

Comment: obg cara  eu tb fiz uma alteração   nessa funçao do mesmo jeito q vc me mostrou , mas eu estava pensando que quando o retorno  dessa funçao    TheFunction();fosse atribuido para o SimpleCat * rCat  ,estaria apontando para um novo SimpleCat  objeto no caso rCat

Comment: Não, porque nesse caso `rCat` é um ponteiro (foi declarado com `*`). E um ponteiro nada mais é do que um inteiro que guarda um endereço de memória. Logo, você simplesmente retorna o endereço, ao invés de "copiar" o conteúdo de um lugar pra outro.

Comment: nossa cara salvou minha pele valeu mesmo , so uma ultima pergunta tentei imprimir os enderenços  dps dessa alteração na funçao, mas pq o enderenços do ponteiro    simpleCat * rCat  nao apontava para o do ponteiro da funçao  SimpleCat * pFrisky = new SimpleCat(5,9);

Comment: pq queria ver pensei que o endereço da  SimpleCat * pFrisky = new SimpleCat(5,9); seria o mesmo da SimpleCat * rCat

Comment: no caso  SimpleCat * rCat  teria q ter o enderenço de SimpleCat * pFrisky = new SimpleCat(5,9); , mas sempre dava diferentes por isso pensei q retorna um ponteiro na funçao  nao estava funciona

Comment: Por nada. Se a resposta te ajudou, por favor considere [aceitá-la](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta). Deveria ser o mesmo ponteiro impresso. Verifique se vc não cometeu nenhum outro errinho. Ah, e se tiver outra dúvida relacionada: abra uma nova pergunta, ok?