# O que é Resource acquisition is initialization (RAII)?

Tags: terminologia, característica-linguagem, independente-de-linguagem, resources

Vejo eventualmente em respostas aqui do site o termo “RAII” sendo usado, mas não sei exatamente o que isso significa. *Resource acquisition is initialization* me parece meio vago.

- Mas o que, de fato, significa RAII? O que ele é?
- Quais são as motivações por trás dele e que tipos de problema ele procura resolver?

---

<sup>Vejo esse termo sendo frequentemente utilizado no contexto de C++, mas sei que Rust também tem mecanismo similar. Por conta disso não associarei esta pergunta a nenhuma linguagem em específico.</sup>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A sigla já está na pergunta. Esta é uma técnica usada para facilitar o gerenciamento de recursos que um objeto usa vinculando o tempo de vida do recurso (que não deixa de ser um outro objeto) ao tempo de vida do objeto que ele está contido. Assim quando o objeto é criado o recurso é adquirido, e quando o objeto é descartado pela aplicação por qualquer motivo o recurso é liberado junto.

A técnica é considerada um [idioma](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/184238/101), ou seja, é uma forma especifica de escrever algo, é muito parecido com um padrão de projeto, mas é mais simples e livre. Em alguns casos pode ter algum mecanismo na linguagem ou biblioteca que facilite isso, e costuma ser preciso de fato de auxílio do compilador para obter o resultado desejado.

Em geral a técnica exige que se escreva um código ou use algo pronto da biblioteca, se a operação for muito padronizada, para que o recurso seja adquirido na construção do objeto e depois liberado na destruição do objeto.

Geralmente a técnica é associada à linguagens que possuem gerenciamento de memória determinística, assim o objeto é liberado tão logo ele não esteja mais em uso, liberando assim o recurso de forma sincronizada. Linguagens não determinísticas (Java, C#, etc.) nesse aspecto têm dificuldade porque o objeto demora para ser liberado e geralmente você precisa da liberado do recurso logo, até porque é comum que o recurso seja algo pesado e externo à aplicação, assim exige um outro mecanismo. E por isso vê muito em C++ e Rust.

C tem dificuldade para usar porque a linguagem não controla o tempo de vida dos objetos de nenhuma forma, então dá para fazer, mas é problema do programador gerenciar isso, não é tão bom, robusto e fácil ou ainda portável, e pode criar algum *overhead*, comparando com as linguagens citadas antes.

Com sua adoção você tem menos dificuldade para gerenciar o tempo de vida dos recursos, caso contrário terá sempre que lembrar que o recurso precisa ser liberado quando o objeto é destruído.

Note que o objeto pode estar em qualquer área da memória, só o tempo de vida dele é conta. Algumas linguagens não determinísticas possuem técnica que ajuda quando o objeto está na pilha, mas as linguagens com RAII real controlam o tempo de vida em qualquer situação, pelo menos se feito da maneira correta. Pode haver o controle em cascata. Então um objeto que está na pilha destruído será o gatilho para destruição de todos objetos associados que usam o RAII, mesmo os que estão fora da pilha, apenas o gatilho inicial precisa estar na pilha.

[Mais detalhes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_acquisition_is_initialization).

[Documentação C++](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii).

[Exemplo Rust](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/scope/raii.html).

[Relacionado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2477/101). E [também](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/83886/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 2):

É uma técnica que equipara a criação de um objeto na pilha com a alocação de um recurso dinâmico (memória na heap, arquivo aberto, etc.). Quando o objeto sai de escopo, o recurso é automaticamente desalocado.

O objeto é sempre manipulado por valor, não por ponteiro, assim a checagem de escopo normal do compilador garante que o recurso associado vai ser alocado e desalocado na hora certa.

Evitando-se a alocação explícita, evita-se os problemas comuns em C/C++ de vazamento de recursos, ponteiros inválidos sendo usados depois de caírem fora de escopo, etc.

A programação da classe desse objeto não é necessariamente mais complexa, pois basta alocar os recursos dinâmicos na construção, e desalocar na destruição, que o compilador garante que serão feitas.

Um outro caso em que o RAII tem desempenho excepcional é no tratamento de exceções. Quando ocorre uma exceção e o controle do programa volta muitos escopos (digamos, A() chama B() que chama C() que chama D(), ocorre uma exceção que é capturada por A()) o compilador garante que todos os objetos criados ao longo do caminho são devidamente destruídos. Porém, isto não acontece com os objetos em ponteiros, criados com new.

Então, se seu programa usa exceções, provavelmente tem de usar RAII.

Os "smart pointers" são uma ferramenta para lidar com aqueles objetos que têm de ser criados com new, permitindo que o RAII também se aplique a itens alocados dinamicamente.

Com "smart pointers", você pode escrever o programa inteiro sem precisar usar "delete" lugar nenhum, pois os objetos são deletados automaticamente quando o smart pointer cai fora do escopo, e também quando acontecem exceções.