# O que é um context manager em Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, característica-linguagem

O que são *context managers* em Python? Sei que podem ser utilizados por meio de blocos `with`.

- Quais problemas um *context manager* resolve?
- Como ele funciona?
- O jeito idiomático para utilizá-los é com `with`? Existem outros jeitos de usá-los?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ele é a aplicação do padrão de projeto chamado [*Dispose pattern*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dispose_pattern) que é bem conhecido em Java ou C#.

Ele consiste em um mecanismo que garante que um determinado recurso seja descartado ao final do seu uso, independente do que aconteça, um erro por exemplo, não deixa de encerrar esse recurso. Geralmente ele é usado para fechar esse recurso e descartar o manipulador de um serviço ou sistema operacional, por isso ele é usado com recursos externos à aplicação.

Ele automatiza de forma adequada o fechamento do recurso.

Ele é acionado com o `with` (ele cria o contexto), desde que o objeto esteja preparado para o padrão. Então:

```
with open('some_file', 'w') as opened_file:
    opened_file.write('Hola!')
```

é o mesmo que escrever (em última instância):

```
file = open('some_file', 'w')
try:
    file.write('Hola!')
finally:
    file.close()
```

Portanto por [*duck typing*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/574146/101) o objeto deve ter os métodos `__enter__()` e `__exit__()` que são métodos que sempre serão chamados pelo `with` na criação do objeto ou quando ele deve ser descartado, respectivamente. Exemplo em código que você poderia criar:

```
class File(object):
    def __init__(self, file_name, method):
        self.file_obj = open(file_name, method)
    def __enter__(self):
        return self.file_obj
    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        self.file_obj.close()
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Syntax/With.py).

É possível chamar os métodos manualmente (sem `with`), mas aí pode cometer algum erro ou chamar em momento errado.

Geralmente este padrão é necessário em linguagens que não permitem [RAII](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/528771/101), que é um mecanismo mais simples, confiável e eficiente. Linguagens com gerenciamento automático não determinístico de memória geralmente tem dificuldade para fazer RAII.

Até onde eu sei Python gerencia memória de forma determinística (usa contagem de referência) e por isso permite RAII. Mas pode ser que seja detalhe de implementação e a linguagem não garanta isso. Talvez em algumas raras situações (não o que é mostrado nos exemplos) pode haver um indeterminismo por causa do ciclo de referência (coletado por um *tracing* GC). Ou o fato da linguagem não ter escopo menor que a função, o que poderia em alguns casos complicar o RAII correto e imediato. Tentei achar algo que explique porque então o DP é necessário, e encontrei uma [resposta no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5071376/221800).

Tem algumas sofisticações que podem ser usadas e pode ver na referência abaixo. Existe até um [módulo para lidar melhor com essa situação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html).

[Fonte](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/context_managers.html). [PEP do `with`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/).